# How to view explain plan for a DB2 Stored Procedure in IBM DataStudio?

Tags: db2, ibm-data-studio

How to view the access plan for the entire SP along with the cost in IBM DataStudio, I am able to view it for a single query but when I do the same for a Stored Procedure it throws an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer, using db2expln executable from the command window, I was able to generate the execution plan for the stored procedures.